# Doubts on Lists for custom class on Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, data-binding

Using Visual Studio Express 2010 for Windows Phone | C# | Silverlight

Lets say I have created a class called Person and it has two properties: name(string) and amount(int).

```
List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
```

I want to create a List of Person, with no items to start with. The user will add the items to that list. However I'm not able to access this list from different pages of the app so instances of Person can be added on event handlers on a different page. Also the information from the lists is need to be accessed from another page. Is there any where I can create the list so it can be accessed globally?

Or am I missing a key concept on lists and databinding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything (I hope; if you are, I'm missing it too!).

What I've done in the past is, in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public List<Person> peopleList { get; set; }
    public static App Instance { get {return (App) Application.Current;}}
....
```

Then, access your data with `App.Instance.peopleList` across your application.

That example is from https://github.com/capnfabs/timecard-wp7/blob/master/App.xaml.cs

Comment: You need to mark your `Person` class `public`: `public class Person...`

Comment: Noted. Now when I try to to use `App.Instance.peopleList.Add(new Person() {Name="Hello", Paid=4, Spent=3});`  I get NullReferenceException on that line. P.S. The Person class has those 3 properties.

Comment: Your list has not been initialised. Try somewhere in your code (App constructor maybe) to add `App.Instance.peopleList = new List<Person>();`.